# WCF Refusing to Attach ClientCredentials to Requests

Tags: vb.net, wcf, soap, wcf-security

I have a web service I'm trying to interface with however no matter what I try it is refusing to send the clients credentials along with the request.

The security block in my app.config looks like

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Then I use the service proxy like this:

```
Dim MyUploadEvent As New EventUploadWSv1.EventUploadWSv1PortTypeClient("IEventUploadWSv1Port")
Dim request As New EventUploadWSv1.webservice_source_event_FileUploadRequest

' First Thing I tried
MyUploadEvent.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "..."
MyUploadEvent.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..."

' Also Tried this based on a question here and a couple of blogs
'Dim defaultCredentials As ClientCredentials
'Dim loginCredentials As New ClientCredentials()

'loginCredentials.UserName.UserName = "..."
'loginCredentials.UserName.Password = "..."

'defaultCredentials = MyUploadEvent.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find(Of ClientCredentials)()
'MyUploadEvent.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(defaultCredentials)
'MyUploadEvent.Endpoint.Behaviors.Insert(0, loginCredentials)

' Configure Request Object

' This throws an exception
MyUploadEvent.fileUpload(request)
```

I have also tried using every other ClientCredentials field (MyUploadEvent.ClientCredentials and MyUploadEvent.ClientFactory.ClientCredentials) but the server keeps returning a message telling me no SOAP authentication information is attached. I've checked the message being sent over the wire and there is no mention of the username or password anywhere. I am clearly missing something here that I shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `TransportWithMessageCredential` security mode. Transport simply uses only configurations defined in `Transport` element and `Message` element is completely ignored..